# Best way to toggle a property in an array

Tags: javascript

I am runing this function that finds an object in an array and toggles the boolean `lead` property.

I am actually doing this in react so in there I do change the data via state and in the end if I run it again it would toggle `Gary` true/false, so it works fine.

My question is regarding the JavaScript code itself, it feels a bit convoluted, is there a better way?

```js
const people = [
  {
    "name": "Olivia",
    "lead": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Gary",
    "lead": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Adam",
    "lead": false
  }
]

const toggleLead = (name) => {

  const values = [...people].map(person =>
    person.name === name
      ? {
          ...person,
          lead: !person.lead
        }
      : { ...person }
  )
 
  return values
}

console.log(toggleLead('Gary'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished via an XOR,  or boolean not equal in other words.

```js
const people = [
  {
    "name": "Olivia",
    "lead": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Gary",
    "lead": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Adam",
    "lead": false
  }
]

const toggleLead = (name) =>
    [...people].map(person =>
        ({
            ...person,
            lead: person.lead !== (person.name===name)
        })
    )

console.log(toggleLead('Gary'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great and it is a lot more concise